# Server responded with 0 code issue in Dropzone.js

Tags: dropzone.js

Im used [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation), I Have some issue for this, I'm uploaded some image,after displayed this error `Server responded with 0 code.` 
look at my attached image you can understand it
[image]

**html code**

```
 <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone"><div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div></form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue can have several reasons. How big are the files you are uploading? How long does the server execute a script? Which maximum file sizes are allowed to upload? 
I assume, this will be mainly an issue of the webserver settings instead of `dropzone.js`.

See this link for some ideas:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/701

Comment: Actually I don't know what happened to the issue on github. The issue on the github page seems to be gone. https://github.com/enyo/dropzone

Comment: they migrate to gitlab

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a browser issue because i was using dropzone.js on three different sections. For two of them it was working fine but after adding a third one, the third was giving me the error. But after trying it on a different browser it was okay.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue. It was related to running the script on a **non HTTPS** website. Once I switched from **http** to **https** it started to work properly. Thought it might be helpful for some of you guys.

Comment: You are right it's working for me also after switching

Comment: @IslamEmam Glad to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Check the config file and the base url name. If your website has SSL it should be **https://** and if not it should be **http://**

Comment: Your answer is exactly like @aiddev's answer, please check other answers to avoid posting duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of I had Dropzone.js in **Sub Domain** and form action (server side php script for file upload) was an address in **main Domain**.

upload script and dropzone form must be in same domains.

update: I think it's also possible for different domains with setting header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in dropzone [header config](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-headers).